# Unique Visits to Website

Tags: php, mysql, unique, counter

how would i make it so that only unique ip addresses increment the count? The code works all fine except that fact

```
<?php 
include('core/init.php');
banned_redirect();
include('includes/overall/header.php');

$counter='';//initilize counter
$sql="SELECT counter FROM tb_counter";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$counter=$rows['counter'];

// if count is empty
if(empty($counter)){
$counter=1;
$insertCounter="INSERT INTO tb_counter set counter='".$counter."'";
$result1=mysql_query($insertCounter);
}

echo "You are visitor num=>". $counter;

// increment visitor count
$increasecounter=$counter+1;
$sql2="update tb_counter set counter='".$increasecounter."'";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);
?>
```

Comment: Can you define a unique visit, and how this doesn't work?

Comment: To know that a IP is unique at your website, then you need to store that IP. So perhaps as a hash or just the IP. A table as timestamp column and IP. The counter is the count(IP) from your table. You just insert the IP if it doesnt exist.

Comment: Could you provide some code, I am new to php coding, im only 15

Comment: Complete code to take a look at https://github.com/defuse/phpcount

Comment: IP is not user unique, so this fails from the start